# AngularJS consuming REST Service

Tags: angularjs

I need to code an AngularJS page which displays some JSON data coming from a REST Service.
The REST service when invoked displays this JSON example data:

```
[{"key":"ABX1234","value":"Network Hub"}]
```

Here is the HTML page that I'm using to retrieve the data:

```
<html ng-app>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function Hello($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('http://host/json').
                success(function(data) {
                    $scope.json = data;
                });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="Hello">
            <p>The ID is {{json.key}}</p>
            <p>The content is {{json.value}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately nothing is displayed as json.key or json.value. Can you help me to find out what is the issue ?
Thanks!

Comment: can you log return data if it is correct or not?

Comment: I just recently did this. Have you looked at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource ? I was able to pull my json data out using $resource('path/to/json',{}); and then querying that to get the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
 <div ng-controller="Hello">   
    <div ng-repeat="json in json">
                <p>The ID is {{json.key}}</p>
                <p>The content is {{json.value}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You are getting array of objects. It needs to be iterated.